# NSUserDefaults: application.plist is reset whenever app starts

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I am using NSUserDefaults to store my app settings/configuration.

The code responsible to saving defaults is below:

```
NSUserDefaults * standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// saving settings
[standardUserDefaults setObject:address.text forKey:@"URL"];
[standardUserDefaults setObject:username.text forKey:@"username"];
[standardUserDefaults setObject:password.text forKey:@"password"];

// synchronize the settings
[standardUserDefaults synchronize];
```

Indeed, the settings seem to have been saved. I open plist file from Libary/Preferences and see that the values are saved. I see those after my method is finished working and [even after] after closing the app.

My problem: whenever I start my app again, the saved values are gone from the plist file[the keys are still present], and I obviously cannot load my preferences.

Please advise.

Comment: It is a good point, but I need help on subject. App architecture is way out of scope.

Comment: Where in your app do you have this code, and where are you trying to access the values when you reopen the app?

Comment: Saving preferences obviously works. When I exit the app, as I mentioned - preferences are [still] in the plist file. 
Whenever the app is started/opened, the values are gone. I load them inside
    viewDidLoad
method of one of the views.

Comment: "Inside my methods" is a useless response. You need to show more context, on where you create the defaults, and where you try to access them.

Comment: Do not use NSUserDefaults to save credential, it's really easy to read them just by attaching and iPhone to a computer using a USB cable or inspecting a backup.
There is a place for saving credential and it is the "keychain".

Comment: Where are you doing the save noted above? If you are doing that in ViewDidLoad is it possible you are overwriting your plist with nil values? Do you have an initialization step that primes the plist with a set of defaults and are those defaults nil? Once you have written to the plist the values won't change until you write to them again or overwrite the plist file. Yes, your code looks valid for writing to a plist, but what else are you doing regarding NSUserDefaults in your code?

Answer (score -1):

You can use to save Settings:

```
    NSMutableDictionary *dictSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dictSetting setValue:address.text forKey:@"URL"];
    [dictSetting setValue:username.text forKey:@"username"];
    [dictSetting setValue:password.text forKey:@"password"];     
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:dictSetting forKey:@"SETTINGS"];
    [defaults synchronize];
```

to Retrive Setting:

```
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSDictionary *dictSettingData = [defaults objectForKey:@"SETTINGS"];
    NSString *url = [dictSettingData valueForKey:@"URL"];
    NSString *username = [dictSettingData valueForKey:@"username"];
    NSString *password = [dictSettingData valueForKey:@"password"];
```